# If $ (1+i)×(1+2i)×...×(1+ ni) = A+iB $ , then $ 2 . 5 . 10 ... (1+n^2) = ? $

Tags: complex-numbers

I am new to complex numbers.

If $$ (1+i)(1+2i)(1+3i) ... (1+ ni) = A + iB $$ where $ i = \sqrt{-1} $
Then how to find the value of $ 2 . 5 . 10 ... (1+n^2)  $

Comment: consider the modulus

Comment: Small rant: You should be _really_ careful with square root signs when dealing with complex numbers. Students learning complex numbers for the first time would avoid so many mistakes and misconceptions if only they learned $i^2 = -1$ rather than $i =\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: @Arthur so we can take any of $ i = ± \sqrt{-1} $ ? According to our purpose

Comment: @MaanavRoy Yes, as long as we're consistent within any single context. That is one way of looking at complex conjugation: switching which $\pm\sqrt{-1}$ we choose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the complex conjugate

$$
\overline{LHS}=(1-i)(1-2i)\ldots (1-ni)=A-iB
$$

and see what happens when you multiply them together.

Comment: $ LHS × conjugate(LHS) $ Becomes $ 2.5.10..... = A^2 + B^2 $

Comment: Meanwhile, need is of : "How can I interpret the thing like you?" OR "How do you think of multiplying by conjugate will give that $ 2.5.10....(n^2 + 1) $ ?" Answers about above two questions should also have been mentioned, as these things are $ more $ $ important $ than finding the answer only. (Maybe to me, because I am new to complex numbers)

Comment: Really it's just a case of narrowing down what you can use from the beginner toolkit. You'll know from any basic introduction that you can add, subtract, multiply and divide complex numbers just like you can with reals, but in addition to this you have the modulus and complex conjugate to play with (still beginner level). The relations $z\overline{z}=||z||^2$ and $\overline{z}\cdot\overline{w}=\overline{zw}$ are easily proven and used, so to a beginner, I would suggest proving and applying these new rules to see how they interact with each other.

Comment: For this problem though, note that if $z=1+ib$ then $z\overline{z}=||z||^2=1+b^2$, and this looks awfully similar to what you asked in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers, then $|zw|=|z|\cdot|w|$.